# Why does my program close after I type something in a second time

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I have this code here:

```
    string code1 = null;
    Console.Write("Username: " + Environment.UserName.ToString() + ">");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == "info")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Info:");
    }
    else if (line == "Set Code")
    {
        if (code1 == null)
        {
            Console.Write("TEST");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'Set Code' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");
            Console.Write("Username: " + Environment.UserName.ToString() + ">");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'" + line + "' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

When I type something in, like "null", then it will run the else code. If I try to type something in again, then it closes the console. Why does it do that?

Comment: Just one question - why it should not close?

Comment: You would have to have a while loop that checks for user input, or some specific string, otherwise your program ends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to put the code into a while loop, it will not close. Here is the edited code:

```
string code1 = null;
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("Username: " + Environment.UserName.ToString() + ">");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == "info")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Info:");
    }
    else if (line == "Set Code")
    {
        if (code1 == null)
        {
            Console.Write("TEST");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'Set Code' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");
            Console.Write("Username: " + Environment.UserName.ToString() + ">");
        }
    }
    else if (line == "quit")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'" + line + "' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");
    }
}
```

Comment: I will mark as correct when I can. I have to wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `ReadLine()` will wait for user input as you noticed. You type "null" and it enters the

```
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("'" + line + "' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");
}
```

control flow.

When you reach the second `ReadLine()`, you can type anything but when you do so and type enter, the program has nothing else to do and therefore exits.

You should try making a loop if you want a never ending input.